# Bootstrap 5 Carousel not sliding

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, bootstrap-5

I want to include a carousel in my page and it does not slide, only shows first image. The other bootstrap components do work, here's my code:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="./img/slider/slider1.png" class="d-block w-100 active" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="./img/slider/slider2.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="./img/slider/slider3.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

I literally copypasted from bootstrap docs and it's still not working.

Comment: just for clarification, in your title and in your tags you specifically mention `bootstrap-5`. In your provided code however you only use `bootstrap-4.1.x`. What bootstrap do you use now?

Comment: The code in your snippet is calling for bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js, but the code for your carousel is for Bootstrap 5 - check your CDN links

Comment: **Vote to close**: Issue is not reproduciable or caused by a typo. The issue is caused by linking the wrong bottstrap library.

Comment: @tacoshy, thank you for your comment. I was having this issue. I just created a new ASP.Net MVC 5 project, and the Bootstrap version that is installed locally is 4.3.1. But the current version of Bootstrap is 5.1. So now I commented out the reference to the local Bootstrap, and now I am getting it from their cdn, and my carousel is working! Thank you.

Comment: For those who are using the `bootstrap` class utility by directly calling the class as with the docs here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/carousel/. The sliding animation for the carousel seems to not work until I added this line `import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"`, along with `import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"`. These lines could be added in the root `index.js` file or in the individual files respectively.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you're linking the incorrect Boostrap libraries. You're using Boostrap 5 code, but using Boostrap 4 libraries.

CSS for Bootstrap 5:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

JS Bundle:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Here's a working example using the correct libraries:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/100x80?sig=1" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/100x80?sig=2" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/100x80?sig=3" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```